VBA Teams transcript functionality
I have written macros to format a teams transcript. I need the Q) in the statement to be bold, as well as the statement that follows the Q). The A) needs to be bold, but the statement that follows A) does not. With the code I created, only the Q) and A) are bold, not the statements that follow. Can anyone see what is wrong with the macros?

    Public Sub MsNewTeamsVersion()

    On Error Resume Next

   

    Dim doc As Document

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

   

    ' Regular expressions for matching timestamps and speaker names

    Dim regexTimestamp As RegExp

    Dim regexName As RegExp

   

    Dim match As Object

    Dim matches As Object

   

    Dim lines() As String

    Dim isOIGSpeaker As Boolean

    Dim hasTimestamp As Boolean

    Dim sentence As Object

   

    Dim i As Integer

   

    Set regexTimestamp = New RegExp

    Set regexName = New RegExp

   

    ' Pattern to match timestamps in the format [HH:MM]

    'regexTimestamp.pattern = "?([0-9]{1})?:([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})"

    regexTimestamp.pattern = "(?:(\d{1,2}):)?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})"

    regexTimestamp.Global = True

 

    ' Pattern to match speaker names ending with (OIG)

    regexName.pattern = "(\w+\W\s\w+\s\(OIG\))"

    regexName.Global = True

 

    ' Remove shapes

    Call RemoveShapes

   

    ' Remove carriage returns

    doc.Content.text = Replace(doc.Content.text, Chr(11), " ")

    doc.Content.Bold = False

   

    ' Look for timestamps

    Set matches = regexTimestamp.Execute(doc.Content.text)

   

    ' Loop through timestamps and now insert a new line

    ' The previous code collapses everything to one paragraph and

    ' this makes sure the headers have a space after it.

    For Each match In matches

        doc.Content.text = Replace(doc.Content.text, match.Value, match.Value & vbNewLine)

    Next match

   

    'Loop through each paragraph

    For Each para In doc.paragraphs

       

        'Split lines in paragraph

        lines() = Split(para.Range.text, Chr(11)) ' Split paragraph into lines

       

        'Initialize loopers

        i = 0

       

        'Initialize booleans

        isOIGSpeaker = False

        hasTimestamp = False

       

        'Loop through lines in paragraph

        For Each Line In lines

            Set sentence = para.Range.paragraphs(1).Range.Duplicate ' Set "sentence" to the current line

            sentence.Start = para.Range.Start + InStr(para.Range.text, Line) - 1

            sentence.End = sentence.Start + Len(Line)

           

            'Check is speaker is OIG in line

            isOIGSpeaker = CheckOIGSpeaker(sentence.text)

           

            'Check if timestamp in line

            hasTimestamp = CheckTimeStamp(sentence.text)

           

            'Based on if OIG and if has timestamp, process accordingly

            If isOIGSpeaker = True And hasTimestamp = True Then

                sentence.Font.Bold = True

                sentence.InsertAfter vbNewLine & "Q) "

            ElseIf isOIGSpeaker = False And hasTimestamp = True Then

                sentence.Font.Bold = True

                sentence.InsertAfter vbNewLine & "A) "

            Else

                sentence.Font.Bold = False

            End If

           

            'Increment looper

            i = i + 1

        Next Line

    Next para

   

    Call BoldAll("Q)")

    Call BoldAll("A)")

    Call ReplaceDoubleParagraphs

 

    'Call ReplaceTimeWithDurations

  

    'Cleanup

    Set sentence = Nothing

    Set match = Nothing

    Set matches = Nothing

    Set regexTimestamp = Nothing

    Set regexName = Nothing

   

End Sub

 

Private Sub BoldAll(text As String)

 

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find

        .ClearFormatting

        ' Substitute the text you want to make bold

        .text = text

        .Replacement.ClearFormatting

        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True

        .Replacement.text = "^&"

        .Format = True

        .Forward = True

        .Wrap = wdFindStop

        .MatchCase = False

        .MatchWholeWord = False

        .MatchWildcards = False

        .MatchSoundsLike = False

        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With

End Sub

 

 

 

Private Function CheckOIGSpeaker(text As String) As Boolean

    

    'This function checks if there is an OIG Speaker

    

    Dim regexName As RegExp

    Set regexName = New RegExp

    

    With regexName

        .pattern = "(\w+\W\s\w+\s\(OIG\))"

        .Global = True

        .IgnoreCase = True

        If .test(text) Then

            CheckOIGSpeaker = True

        Else

            CheckOIGSpeaker = False

        End If

    End With

   

End Function

 

Private Function CheckTimeStamp(text As String) As Boolean

   

    'This function checks if there is a timestamp in the text

   

    Dim regexTimestamp As RegExp

   

    Set regexTimestamp = New RegExp

   

    With regexTimestamp

        '.pattern = "?([0-9]{1})?:([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})"

        .pattern = "(?:(\d{1,2}):)?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})"

        .Global = True

        .IgnoreCase = True

        If .test(text) Then

            CheckTimeStamp = True

        Else

            CheckTimeStamp = False

        End If

    End With

   

End Function

 

 

Private Sub RemoveShapes()

 

    'This method removes all shapes

   

    For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1

        ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Delete

    Next i

 

End Sub

 

Private Function FindRegexMatches(text As String, pattern As String) As Object

   

    Dim rx As RegExp

   

    Set rx = New RegExp

   

    With rx

        .pattern = pattern

        .Global = True

        .IgnoreCase = True

        Set FindRegexMatches = rx.Execute(text)

    End With

 

 

End Function

 

Private Sub ReplaceTimeWithDurations()

   

    Dim doc As Document

    Dim match As Object

    Dim matches As Object

    Dim prevMatchVal As Date

    Dim prevMatchText As String

    Dim strDuration As String

 

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

   

    prevMatchText = Format("00:00:00", "HH:MM:SS")

    prevMatchValue = TimeValue(prevMatchText)

   

    Set matches = FindRegexMatches(doc.Content.text, "([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})")

   

    For Each match In matches

        strDuration = prevMatchText & " - " & Format(TimeValue(Format(match.Value, "HH:MM:SS")) + prevMatchValue, "HH:MM:SS")

        prevMatchValue = TimeValue(Format(match.Value, "HH:MM:SS")) + prevMatchValue

        prevMatchText = Format(prevMatchValue, "HH:MM:SS")

        'doc.Content.text = Replace(doc.Content.text, match.Value, strDuration, 1, 1, vbBinaryCompare)

        With doc.Content.Find

            .text = match.Value

            .Replacement.text = strDuration

            .Format = True

            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

        End With

    Next match

   

    

    

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceDoubleParagraphs()

    ' Find and replace double paragraph marks with single paragraph marks

    With Selection.Find

        .text = "^p^p"

        .Replacement.text = "^p"

        .Forward = True

        .Wrap = wdFindContinue

        .Format = False

        .MatchCase = False

        .MatchWholeWord = False

        .MatchWildcards = False

        .MatchSoundsLike = False

        .MatchAllWordForms = False

    End With

   

    ' Execute the replacement

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub




On Error Resume Next

   

    Dim doc As Document

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

   

    ' Regular expressions for matching timestamps and speaker names

    Dim regexTimestamp As RegExp

    Dim regexName As RegExp

   

    Dim match As Object

    Dim matches As Object

   

    Dim lines() As String

    Dim isOIGSpeaker As Boolean

    Dim hasTimestamp As Boolean

    Dim sentence As Object

   

    Dim i As Integer

   

    Set regexTimestamp = New RegExp

    Set regexName = New RegExp

   

    ' Pattern to match timestamps in the format [HH:MM]

    'regexTimestamp.pattern = "?([0-9]{1})?:([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})"

    regexTimestamp.pattern = "(?:(\d{1,2}):)?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})"

    regexTimestamp.Global = True

 

    ' Pattern to match speaker names ending with (OIG)

    regexName.pattern = "(\w+\W\s\w+\s\(OIG\))"

    regexName.Global = True

 

    ' Remove shapes

    Call RemoveShapes

   

    ' Remove carriage returns

    doc.Content.text = Replace(doc.Content.text, Chr(11), " ")

    doc.Content.Bold = False

   

    ' Look for timestamps

    Set matches = regexTimestamp.Execute(doc.Content.text)

   

    ' Loop through timestamps and now insert a new line

    ' The previous code collapses everything to one paragraph and

    ' this makes sure the headers have a space after it.

    For Each match In matches

        doc.Content.text = Replace(doc.Content.text, match.Value, match.Value & vbNewLine)

    Next match

   

    'Loop through each paragraph

    For Each para In doc.paragraphs

       

        'Split lines in paragraph

        lines() = Split(para.Range.text, Chr(11)) ' Split paragraph into lines

       

        'Initialize loopers

        i = 0

       

        'Initialize booleans

        isOIGSpeaker = False

        hasTimestamp = False

       

        'Loop through lines in paragraph

        For Each Line In lines

            Set sentence = para.Range.paragraphs(1).Range.Duplicate ' Set "sentence" to the current line

            sentence.Start = para.Range.Start + InStr(para.Range.text, Line) - 1

            sentence.End = sentence.Start + Len(Line)

           

            'Check is speaker is OIG in line

            isOIGSpeaker = CheckOIGSpeaker(sentence.text)

           

            'Check if timestamp in line

            hasTimestamp = CheckTimeStamp(sentence.text)

           

            'Based on if OIG and if has timestamp, process accordingly

            If isOIGSpeaker = True And hasTimestamp = True Then

                sentence.Font.Bold = True

                sentence.InsertAfter vbNewLine & "Q) "

            ElseIf isOIGSpeaker = False And hasTimestamp = True Then

                sentence.Font.Bold = True

                sentence.InsertAfter vbNewLine & "A) "

            Else

                sentence.Font.Bold = False

            End If

           

            'Increment looper

            i = i + 1

        Next Line

    Next para

   

    Call BoldAll("Q)")

    Call BoldAll("A)")

    Call ReplaceDoubleParagraphs

 

    'Call ReplaceTimeWithDurations

  

    'Cleanup

    Set sentence = Nothing

    Set match = Nothing

    Set matches = Nothing

    Set regexTimestamp = Nothing

    Set regexName = Nothing

   

End Sub

 

Private Sub BoldAll(text As String)

 

    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find

        .ClearFormatting

        ' Substitute the text you want to make bold

        .text = text

        .Replacement.ClearFormatting

        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True

        .Replacement.text = "^&"

        .Format = True

        .Forward = True

        .Wrap = wdFindStop

        .MatchCase = False

        .MatchWholeWord = False

        .MatchWildcards = False

        .MatchSoundsLike = False

        .MatchAllWordForms = False

        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

    End With

End Sub

 

 

 

Private Function CheckOIGSpeaker(text As String) As Boolean

    

    'This function checks if there is an OIG Speaker

    

    Dim regexName As RegExp

    Set regexName = New RegExp

    

    With regexName

        .pattern = "(\w+\W\s\w+\s\(OIG\))"

        .Global = True

        .IgnoreCase = True

        If .test(text) Then

            CheckOIGSpeaker = True

        Else

            CheckOIGSpeaker = False

        End If

    End With

   

End Function

 

Private Function CheckTimeStamp(text As String) As Boolean

   

    'This function checks if there is a timestamp in the text

   

    Dim regexTimestamp As RegExp

   

    Set regexTimestamp = New RegExp

   

    With regexTimestamp

        '.pattern = "?([0-9]{1})?:([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})"

        .pattern = "(?:(\d{1,2}):)?(\d{1,2}):(\d{2})"

        .Global = True

        .IgnoreCase = True

        If .test(text) Then

            CheckTimeStamp = True

        Else

            CheckTimeStamp = False

        End If

    End With

   

End Function

 

 

Private Sub RemoveShapes()

 

    'This method removes all shapes

   

    For i = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1

        ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).Delete

    Next i

 

End Sub

 

Private Function FindRegexMatches(text As String, pattern As String) As Object

   

    Dim rx As RegExp

   

    Set rx = New RegExp

   

    With rx

        .pattern = pattern

        .Global = True

        .IgnoreCase = True

        Set FindRegexMatches = rx.Execute(text)

    End With

 

 

End Function

 

Private Sub ReplaceTimeWithDurations()

   

    Dim doc As Document

    Dim match As Object

    Dim matches As Object

    Dim prevMatchVal As Date

    Dim prevMatchText As String

    Dim strDuration As String

 

    Set doc = ActiveDocument

   

    prevMatchText = Format("00:00:00", "HH:MM:SS")

    prevMatchValue = TimeValue(prevMatchText)

   

    Set matches = FindRegexMatches(doc.Content.text, "([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})")

   

    For Each match In matches

        strDuration = prevMatchText & " - " & Format(TimeValue(Format(match.Value, "HH:MM:SS")) + prevMatchValue, "HH:MM:SS")

        prevMatchValue = TimeValue(Format(match.Value, "HH:MM:SS")) + prevMatchValue

        prevMatchText = Format(prevMatchValue, "HH:MM:SS")

        'doc.Content.text = Replace(doc.Content.text, match.Value, strDuration, 1, 1, vbBinaryCompare)

        With doc.Content.Find

            .text = match.Value

            .Replacement.text = strDuration

            .Format = True

            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

        End With

    Next match

   

    

    

End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceDoubleParagraphs()

    ' Find and replace double paragraph marks with single paragraph marks

    With Selection.Find

        .text = "^p^p"

        .Replacement.text = "^p"

        .Forward = True

        .Wrap = wdFindContinue

        .Format = False

        .MatchCase = False

        .MatchWholeWord = False

        .MatchWildcards = False

        .MatchSoundsLike = False

        .MatchAllWordForms = False

    End With

   

    ' Execute the replacement

    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub

Expected the statements after the Q) to be bold.

All you should need is:
Sub TeamsFmt()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
  .Execute Text:="Q\)*A\)", MatchWildcards:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll, _
    Forward:=True, Wrap:=wdFindContinue, Format:=True, ReplaceWith:="^&"
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

